# Get intellisense in editor from compiled code in docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, intellisense

I've been looking a while for this but don't seem to be able to find a decent solution without creating extra mess in my workspace.

Is it possible to use an editor, such as VSCode, and make its **intellisense** use compiled code that resides inside a **docker container** (or multiple)?

One way to perhaps accomplish is this by creating shared volumes that link the node_modules and the compiled folder.

In my workspace i'm using NodeJS, Npm modules and my editor of choice is, visual studio code. The workspace setup is launched using **docker-compose**

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Hi, you've post a great question and it seems that nobody knows the answer :) I'm searching for the same stuff, and would like to ask you – did you find the way how it could be configured? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The VS Code Team recently announced [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development), which contains [The Remote - Containers extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers)

> The Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension lets you use a Docker container as a full-featured development environment. It allows you to open any folder inside (or mounted into) a container and take advantage of VS Code's full feature set.
>
> This lets VS Code provide a local-quality development experience — including **full IntelliSense (completions)**, code navigation, and debugging — regardless of where your tools (or code) is located.

[source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

Note that for now it requires the [VS Code Insiders build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)